# Isolating pandas columns using boolean logic in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to grab the rows of a data frame that satisfy one or both of the following boolean statements:

```
1) df['colName'] == 0
2) df['colName'] == 1
```

I've tried these, but neither one works (throws errors):

```
df = df[df['colName']==0 or df['colName']==1]
df = df[df['colName']==0 | df['colName']==1]
```

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing `()`

```
df = df[(df['colName']==0) | (df['colName']==1)]
```

this will probably raise a copy warning but will still works.

if you don't want the copy warning, use an indexer such has:

```
indexer = df[(df['colName']==0) | (df['colName']==1)].index
df = df.loc[indexer,:]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could clean up what you've done using `eq` instead of `==`

```
df[df.colName.eq(0) | df.colName.eq(1)]
```

For this case, I recommend using `isin`

```
df[df.colName.isin([0, 1])]
```

Using `query` also works but is slower

```
df.query('colName in [0, 1]')
```

---

***Timing***
`isin` is quickest on `df` defined below
`df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=10000), columns=['colName'])`

[image]